# Determine if UITextfield is empty after deleting characters one by one

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a view controller with two `UITableViewCells` and each cell contains a `UITextField`. In my navigation bar I have a right bar button called "Save" that is disabled unless both textfields contain text. The default state of the save button is disabled. The transition from disabled to enabled works fine, but disabling the button when one of the textfields is emptied is difficult.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if title == "Password"{
        if textField.tag == 1{
            if (textField.text?.isEmpty)!{
                passwordField1Empty = true
            }
            else {
                passwordField1Empty = false
            }
        }
        else if textField.tag == 2 {
            if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
                passwordField2Empty = true
            }
            else {
                passwordField2Empty = false
            }
        }

        if passwordField1Empty == false && passwordField2Empty == false {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    }
    return true

}
```

Whats causing the issue is if a user goes back and deletes each character in the text field one by one, `textField.text?.isEmpty` will get called each time. When there is one last character left `textField.text?.isEmpty` will get called before deleting the last character, so it ends up returning false. `textField.text?.isEmpty` won't return true unless the user presses the delete button one more time, even though there is nothing left to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are `overriding` the `shouldChangeCharactersIn()` method which is being called before the actual character has been added/deleted. Therefore, if you want to catch the case of the user deleting the last character you have 2 options:

1. You can replace the `if (textField.text?.isEmpty)` with `if (textField.text?.characters.count == 1 && replacementString == "")`.
2. You can also update your string before your `if statement` like this:

   ```
   let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
   ```

   After this you can check `if (newString.isEmpty)`.

Comment: This does the job, except `newString` does not have a `text` property - its just `newString.isEmpty`.

Comment: Oh, true. Sorry for the mistake! Just edited my answer!

Answer (score 0):

So there are two characters in the textField. The user hits delete. shouldChangeCharactersIn gets called. Nothing has changed yet and textField.text?.count == 2. You return true and the character is deleted. The user hits delete a second time. shouldChangeCharactersIn is called again. At this point the last character hasn't been deleted yet textField.text?.count == 1 which is why textField.text?.isEmpty == false. It wont be true until the user tries to edit the text again.